# Rescheduling of a ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency

The following piece of code is called from a JMenuItem's ActionListener. Simply it launches a jar file.

```
ScheduledExecutorService schedulerExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
Callable<Process> callable = new Callable<Process>() {

    @Override
    public Process call() throws Exception {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java -jar D:\\MovieLibrary.jar");
        return p;
    }
};
FutureTask<Process> futureTask = new FutureTask<Process>(callable);
schedulerExecutor.submit(futureTask);
schedulerExecutor.shutdown();               

System.exit(0);
```

But the problem is, it is execution only once. Not repeatedly. That means the `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java -jar D:\\MovieLibrary.jar");` is not called for second time.

How can I make to right?

Any suggestion is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newScheduledThreadPool(2)` doesn't mean that the thread runs twice. 
It is the size of the pool. 
"submit" the task twice if you want to run it for second time.

```
schedulerExecutor.submit(futureTask);
schedulerExecutor.submit(futureTask);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. No definitely newScheduledThreadPool(2) does not make it run twice. what I understand is it would make the task to use two threads. Also I have tried to submit the task two or more times, but it didn't work. Actually the JMenuItem restart the application it self. But it is restarting only once. :(

Comment: If you try to run MovieLibrary manually from your console, can you run twice?

Comment: No it is executing only once. If I run it from eclipse then it runs twice.

Comment: If you can't run the movielibrary twice from your console with "java -jar D:\\MovieLibrary.jar", then there's an another problem ? Maybe it listens a port which can't be bound twice or something like this, anyway.

Comment: I am really very sorry. I made a mistake, that I wrote new code and build it but forgot to replace D:\\MovieLibrary by that new build. Anyway thanks for your help. :)